# Blender Python Reported texture size limit error

Tags: python, blender

I'm trying to render a Blender 4 scene, using the command line, on a not supported OpenGL virtual Windows machine using Python, and an error is thrown:

```
RuntimeError: Error: Error: Reported texture size limit (0px) is lower than output size (1024px).
```

I'm having the opengl32.dll installed.

The lines raising the error:

```
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = output_path  
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

Does anyone have tips?